# Spring Web Services - WSDL

Tags: web-services, spring

In your wsdl, is it possible to connect directly to the wsdl(i.e - http://(url)?wsdl.

When I copy the wsdl locally to src/main/resources - I am able to connect generate objects including Web Service client, but when I try to connect to the WSDL that I copied from, I cannot generate. Perhaps I am not understanding QName and wsdllocation and even port for that matter.

I have searched fairly extensively on the web and there aren't that many clear cut examples. I know WebServiceTemplate makes things a LOT easier but without connecting to the WSDL, I cannot connect.

All I am trying to do is connect to the client. So it is a question more about Endpoints.

Also is it best practice to copy the WSDL locally. I am asking this because the client that we are working for has a 100 million environments.

Thanks.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WSDL url will be like **http://localhost:8080/<< Context-Name >>/<< ServiceName >>?wsdl**

If you are generating the wsdl by running a server, then localhost:, should be given. If its a direct wsdl file, then try right clicking and opening it using a web browser. It will simply give you the link. You can use the same link to produce client stubs too.